# Email Message record creation through process builder

Tags: workflow, process-builder, singleemailmessage, emailmessage, salesforce-support

I want to create an email message record after sending an email template.

Is there any way to create email message record through process builder or workflow after sending an email alert. So that we can track the sent email template.

We can't use the apex as we reached org limits.

Comment: Which org limits did you reach? There is also [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroKAAS) which was updated not 16 days ago that has been around for 12 years asking for the ability to track email alerts. What you are trying to do might not be possible without apex

Comment: SingleEmailMessage limit - 5000 per org.

Comment: We have raised a case with Salesforce to increase the limit , but we received response from Salesforce the limit can be increased for maximum 90 days.

Comment: There are alot of questions I have around your email as there are often plenty of ways to help reduce email limits. Such as making sure you are sending to SObjects rather then directly to email addresses or using the mass email functionality in conjunction with single email or if your using it for marketing, using a different product to handle the emails.